# redis hmget node.js async/await not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, async-await

I am trying to get some data from redis through node.js using following code :

```
var moment = require("moment");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var crypto = require('crypto');
var redis = require('redis');
var bluebird = require("bluebird");
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);


const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

var KEY_USERS = "auction:users";
var KEY_ADMIN_TOKENS = KEY_USERS + ":admin_tokens";
var KEY_USER_TOKENS = KEY_USERS + ":user_tokens";
var SERVER_PORT = 12251;

var redis_client = bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.createClient({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        no_ready_check: true,
        auth_pass: '****',
}));



redis_client.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('Redis client connected');
});

redis_client.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong with Redis Connection ' + err);
});

server.listen(SERVER_PORT);

console.log('1');

(async () => {

        var response = await isAdminUser('c169024a-8902-4310-8955-ff46516e8703');

        console.log("From Async " + response);        
})()

console.log('2');

// Promise.resolve()
//         .then(() => isAdminUser('c169024a-8902-4310-8955-ff46516e8703'))
//         .then(() => console.log('3'));


console.log("Server Connected and redis initialized.");

async function isAdminUser(token) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                redis_client.hmget(KEY_ADMIN_TOKENS, [token, token], function (error, result) {
                        if (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                                throw error;
                        }
                        console.log("Token Result : " + result);

                        resolve(result);
                });
        });
}
```

Now the issue is, node is waiting for the redis query to complete and moving forward to the next line of code.

Output from the console :

```
1
2
Server Connected and redis initialized.
Redis client connected
Token Result : "my result"
From Async "my result"
```

Desired output :

```
1
2
Redis client connected    
Token Result : "my result"
From Async "my result"
Server Connected and redis initialized.
```

What is it that I am missing / doing wrong ? I have gone through a lot of tutorials / articles suggesting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Async functions are nothing more than a syntax sugar for functions that return promises, and it only makes sense to make a function async if you are using `await` in the function.

Your function `isAdminUser` doesn't use `await`, so it doesn't need `async`. It doesn't actually do anythin there.

Also, you are passing your `redis_client` to `promisifyAll`, but for this to have any effect you need to use the `async` methods in the client.

I refactored your code a little bit to move the client initialization to a promise:

```
const initializeRedisClient = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const redis_client = bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.createClient({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        no_ready_check: true,
        auth_pass: '****',
    }));

    redis_client.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('Redis client connected');
        resolve(redis_client);
    });

    redis_client.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong with Redis Connection ' + err);
        reject(err);
    });
});

(async () => {
    const redis_client = await initializeRedisClient();
    const response = await isAdminUser(redis_client, 'c169024a-8902-4310-8955-ff46516e8703');

    console.log("From Async " + response);
    console.log("Server Connected and redis initialized.");
})()

console.log('2');

async function isAdminUser(redis_client, token) {
    const result = redis_client.hmgetAsync(KEY_ADMIN_TOKENS, [token, token]);

    console.log("Token Result : " + result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Still the output is same :

2
Server Connected and redis initialized.
Redis client connected
Token Result : "date"
From Async "data"

Comment: an await was missing before redis_client.hmgetAsync

Comment: added await still no luck.

Comment: you can move the console.log to the line after initializeRedisClient. But is there something in the result that is wrong, or you are just trying to understand the order in which the events occur?

Comment: actually I am using socket.io and whenever user request or posts any data, I have to check if the user is authenticated / authorized. If I go with above method, that I will have to wrap all my logic around the redis.hmgetasync. What I am trying to do is create a function which checks for the token, and return true/false for the case.

Comment: It should not execute the next line i.e. console.log('2'); before all above operations have been executed.

Comment: you can't have non-async functions awaiting for async functions, so it won't be possible for your function to return true or false. Either you make it return a promise that resolves to true or false, or you pass a callback to isAdminUser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195411/discussion-between-nitin-kabra-and-thiago-barcala).

Comment: i get that, I have also tried to return promise 

async function isAdminUser(token) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                
                redis.redis_client.hmget(KEY_ADMIN_TOKENS, [token, token], function (error, result) {
                        if (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                                throw error;
                        }
                        resolve(result)
                });
        });     
}

which does not yield result